# Why do divs with a percentage width force an inline-block to 100% width?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a simple set of cards that show side-by-side images, which I need to be responsive to screen width. So using simple `inline-block`, I have this structure:

```
<div class="cards" id="ex1">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/5/b/a/7/1194986784455829849basebalm_ganson.svg.med.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/1/4/6/11971185311926706097Gioppino_Basketball.svg.med.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.cards {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #808080;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#ex1 .card {
  width: 35%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

But to my surprise, the parent div, `.cards`, spans the width of the page as if it were `display: block`:

[image]

However, if I hard-code the widths of the `.card` divs, it works as expected. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4k8cnv1/) that compares the two.

Why does `inline-block` not respect percentages that don't add up to 100%? Is there any way to do this with percentages? (I could make them both 50%, but even with `box-sizing: border-box` this can cause them to stack vertically.)

Answer (score 4):

`.cards` has a shrink-to-fit width. That means it will attempt to be only as wide as the contents want (supposing there is enough space).

However, the contents have a percentage width, which depends on `.cards`.

The circular definition is solved like this:

1. The percentages of the contents are treated as `auto`

   That is, the images have their intrinsic width, which is `300px`.
2. `.cards` is sized according to the contents, which no longer depend on `.cards`

   That is, it becomes `300px + 300px = 600px` wide. <sup><sub>Well, in fact slightly more because you have some space in the HTML, see [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/1529630) to avoid it, but let's ignore this.</sub></sup>
3. The contents are sized again, now taking the percentages into account, which are resolved relatively to the width of `.cards` from the previous step.

   That is, the images become `35% * 600px = 210px` wide.

Answer (score 2):

The `inline-block` property occupies 100% space while maintaining the property of being `inline`. However, when a single line on the visual appearance is about to overflow, the inline-property goes on another line.

**For example**:

```
element {
    display: inline; /* Makes the content go on the same line*/
}
element {
    display: inline-block; /* Makes the content go on the same line while not overflowing
                           and going on a different line while about to overflow*/
}
element {
    display: block; /* Makes the content go on different lines*/
}
```

I hope you understand what I mean.